# JQuery Login Area Simulation

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to simulate a login area with jquery.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#login').click(function () {
        $('.teste').show();
        $('#loginarea').hide();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loginarea">
                <form name="htmlform" method="post">
                    <table width="390px">
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top">
                                <label for="username">Username: </label>
                            </td>
                            <td valign="top">
                                <input id="username" type="text" name="username" maxlength="20" size="25" required="required" placeholder="Username">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top">
                                <label for="password">Password: </label>
                            </td>
                            <td valign="top">
                                <input id="password" type="password" name="password" maxlength="100" size="25" required="required" placeholder="Password">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
                                <input id="login" type="submit" value="Login">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
            </div>
<div class="teste" style="display:none;">
                <p>Teste</p>
            </div>
```

The new div can only show off if both username and password's field have value, but if I add a if/else to the script, it doesn't work...

Comment: Omitting the broken code does help troubleshoot the broken code.

Comment: You will also want to event.preventDefault() on your .click function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#login').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if($('#username').val() && $('#password').val()){
            $('form[name=htmlform]').submit();
        }else{
            //all erros msgs
            $('.teste').html('some fields empty');
            $('.teste').show();
        }
    });
});
```

This is a way. But if you want just show the div#teste, I believe you can do the modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for the help. 
I did some changes based on your code and it worked.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#login').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($('#username').val() && $('#password').val()) {
            $('.teste').show();
            $('#loginarea').hide();
        }
        else
        {
            $('#loginarea').append("some fields empty");
            
        }
    });
});
```